# SQL. query: find a warehouse in which this item is not stored

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables: `WAREHOUSE, ITEM, ITEM_DETAILS`

The relationship between them:

```
ITEM - ITEM_DETAILS one to many
WAREHOUSE - ITEM_DETAILS one to many
```

Table `WAREHOUSE`:

```
id | name
---+-------------
 1 | warehouse_01
 2 | warehouse_02
 3 | warehouse_03
```

Table `ITEM`:

```
id | name
---+--------
 1 | item_01    
 2 | item_02    
 3 | item_03
```

Table `ITEM_DETAILS`:

```
id | name            | id_item | warehouse_id | quantity
---+-----------------+---------+--------------+----------
 1 | item_details_01 |    1    |        1     |    10
 2 | item_details_02 |    2    |        2     |    12
 3 | item_details_03 |    3    |        1     |    11
 3 | item_details_04 |    1    |        3     |     8
```

How can I write a query correctly to get a list of WAREHOUSE that do not have this ITEM?

For example, there is warehouse_01, warehouse_02, warehouse_03, and there is an ITEM "item_01", which is in warehouse_03 and in warehouse_01, the result of the query should be warehouse_02.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `not exists`:

```
select w.*
from warehouse w
where not exists (select 1
                  from item_details id
                  where id.warehouse_id = w.id and id.item_id = ?
                 );
```

The `?` is a parameter placeholder for the item you care about.